# Add seconds and epochs to obtain datetime

Tags: date, groovy, time

Beginner learner here, trying to add an array of integers (which are meant to be seconds) to an array of Epochs:

Sample input:

```
AddSeconds = [3,4]
TimeEpoch = [1575165652000, 1576424223000] // Which are 2019-12-01 02:00:52 and 2019-12-15 15:37:03
```

Desired output:

```
endDate = [2019-12-01 02:00:55, 2019-12-15 15:37:07]
```

1. I need to convert the TimeEpoch to dates with "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" format
2. I need to add "AddSeconds" to the obtained dates

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this (I changed your variables to start with a lower-case letter, because Groovy guesses that upper case letter variables are actually classnames, so can cause confusion):

```
addSeconds = [3,4]
timeEpoch = [1575165652000, 1576424223000]

import java.time.*
import java.time.format.*

def formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

def datesAsStrings = [addSeconds, timeEpoch]
    .transpose()
    .collect { a, t -> Instant.ofEpochMilli(t).plusSeconds(a).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime() }
    .collect { d -> d.format(formatter) }

datesAsStrings.each { println it }
```

That takes your two lists, and joins them together with `transpose()`:

```
[ [3, 1575165652000], [4, 1576424223000] ]
```

Then for each of these, we create an instant, add the seconds, and convert it to a LocalDateTime using the current system timezone -- You *need* to consider timezones

Then we convert them to the String format you wanted, and pint each of them out